# Display test file name in Mocha output

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Is there anyway to have mocha display the name of, or group the output by *the test file*?

Given two test files, `./test/testFoo.js` and `./test/testBar.js` I'd like to see something like this when running `mocha test`:

```sh
* testFoo:

  Doing X
    ✓ should return A
    ✓ even with negative input

  Doing Y
    ✓ should return B
    ✓ should return C when called with Egyptian hieroglyphs

* testBar:

  Doing Z
    ✓ should return D
```

(This might be an XY problem. If there are other way to group tests in two levels, I'm just as interested. It's just that the files are already there, as a kind of natural first level group.)

Comment: Have you considered nesting `describe`s?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wow, I did not know that was possible! Thank you!

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#getting-started

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be good using Mocha's `describe` method to logically group your tests. For the output you desire, the structure of your tests would look like:

**/test/testFoo.js**

```
describe('testFoo', () => {
    describe('Doing X', () => {
        it('should return A', () => {
        });

        it('even with negative input', () => {
        });
    });

    describe('Doing Y', () => {
        it('should return B', () => {
        });

        it('should return C when called with Egyptian hieroglyphs', () => {
        });
    });
});
```

**/test/testBar.js**

```
describe('testBar', () => {
    describe('Doing Z', () => {
        it('should return D', () => {
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I personally don't see the reason to create totally redundant wrappers. I prefer grouping by file and leave my tests entirely flat. Easier to read and maintain. Sadly, mocha (at least by default) does not group tests by file name. Jest does, for instance. Further on the benefit of flat structure: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/avoid-nesting-when-youre-testing

Comment: The article you mention is more about `beforeEach` spaghetti and using globals than organization of tests. The author wouldn't lose any of the benefits from using a top-level describe to show a filename.

Comment: So, every time you change the name of the file for whatever reason, you have to change the describe text as well... How is this a benefit? As for the article, I said it's about the benefits of flat structure and it is exactly about that.

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of there being no solution for this every time I went searching for one and built my own reporter:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-spec-reporter-with-file-names

That page contains the details but here they are repeated:

1. install it: `npm i -D mocha-spec-reporter-with-file-names`
2. set it at your reporter

   - cli: `npx mocha --reporter './node_modules/mocha-spec-reporter-with-file-names'`
   - config:

     ```js
     // .mocharc.js

     const SpecReporterWithFileNames = require('mocha-spec-reporter-with-file-names');

     module.exports = {
         reporter: SpecReporterWithFileNames.pathToThisReporter,
     };
     ```

Output currently looks like this:

[image: example output]